# What could cause Django to start failing its own tests after an OS and Django reinstall?

Tags: python, django, testing

I had to reinstall my OS, and so, I reinstalled django 1.1. Since reinstalling, when I run tests in my app, I get several failures from django.contrib.auth.

Logs: http://dpaste.com/178153/

I asked on #django, and no one is too sure what the cause of the errors are. Some of my own code fails its tests, because it's not fully written yet, but that shouldn't cause django to fail it's core tests...

I have included django.contrib.admin, which was mentioned as a possible cause.

EDIT: Starting a fresh project, the same django internal tests fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asking on #django again reveals this is a known bug to do with python 2.6.5 which came with the new version of my OS, and Django 1.1.1.

It has been [patched](http://code.djangoproject.com/changeset/11821) in the development version.

Answer (score 0):

These look like `django.contib.auth` failures. Are including `django.contib.auth` in your installed apps? Have you changed either the [`MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/settings/#middleware-classes) or [`TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/settings/#template-context-processors)
in your settings file? Both of these contain default settings used by the `django.contib.auth` that might cause these failures.

Comment: I have added the 'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware' to MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES. I haven't touched TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS

Comment: So your MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES still contains `django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware`?